# Better nth-child selector

Tags: css, less, css-selectors

My LESS goes this way,

```
.img-preview {
   &:first-child:nth-last-child(6),
   &:first-child:nth-last-child(6) ~ a:nth-child(2),
   &:first-child:nth-last-child(6) ~ a:nth-child(3),
   &:first-child:nth-last-child(6) ~ a:nth-child(4),
   &:first-child:nth-last-child(6) ~ a:nth-child(5) {}
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to select all the elements execpt the last one if there is only 6 childs. Instead of writing the repeated codes like above, is there any way to write this in a better way.

I've tried the following, but its giving error when compiling.

```
.img-preview {
       &:first-child:nth-last-child(6) ~ a:not(:last-child) {}
}
```

Comment: you just need to add a curly bracket } after what you have now

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: Although that selector isn't a correct way to write it, it should still compile without errors at least.

Answer (score 1):

The `~ a:not(:last-child)` portion matches elements that come after the first child, and therefore not the first child itself. You will still need to select `&:first-child:nth-last-child(6)` for that:

```
.img-preview {
    &:first-child:nth-last-child(6),
    &:first-child:nth-last-child(6) ~ &:not(:last-child) {}
}
```